# find the value of x at second derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

The quesion is :
\begin{align}
   \ y= \sqrt{x} ~\text{ find the value of x for which}~ y+ \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 0
    \end{align}

\begin{align}
   \ 
    \end{align}

The answer given is :   x= 1/2

I am not sure how they got this answer so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y=\sqrt { x } $ so plug this  in the equation $$\sqrt { x } +\frac { d }{ dx } \left( \frac { d\left( \sqrt { x }  \right)  }{ dx }  \right) =0\\$$ now here $\frac { d }{ dx } \left( \frac { d\left( \sqrt { x }  \right)  }{ dx }  \right) $ means you should find derivative twice of $y=\sqrt { x } $
$$ \sqrt { x } +\frac { d }{ dx } \left( \frac { 1 }{ 2\sqrt { x }  }  \right) =0\\ \sqrt { x } -\frac { 1 }{ 4x\sqrt { x }  } =0\\ 4{ x }^{ 2 }-1=0\\ x=1/2$$

Comment: Wouldnt I plug the second derivative of y

Comment: i didn't understand your question

Comment: I dont understand what you did, you got the answer but the equation was y= square root of x